# When I tried to pass data to a function from another it shows me a lot of errors

Tags: python

This code worked successfully..

```
import urllib.request
def profanity():
connection = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q='+'bal')
output = connection.read()
print(output)
connection.close()
profanity()
```

But I want run the code like the below it caused problem to me. But I want to pass data which is being read from a local txt file and pass this data to profanity() function. What is to do?

```
import urllib.request

def read_file():
    qoutes=open(r"C:\Python34\profanity.txt")
    a=qoutes.read()

    profanity(a)
    qoutes.close()

def profanity(b):
    connection = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q='+b)
    output = connection.read()
    print(output)
    connection.close()
##profanity()

read_file()
```

The error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\check_profanity.py", line 18, in <module>
read_file()
File "C:\Python34\check_profanity.py", line 8, in read_file
profanity(a)
File "C:\Python34\check_profanity.py", line 12, in profanity
connection = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q='+b)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 462, in open
req = meth(req)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1106, in do_request_
raise URLError('no host given')
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

Comment: How does `"C:\Python34\profanity.txt"` look? If you are trying to read multiple words from that file and test each of those you probably need something like this: `quotes.read().splitlines()` and then iterate over this list.

Comment: Tthe file is a txt file and a passage is in it. I tried your solution but it don't work. But I change the paragraph and just put a single word in it and my previous code run perfectly. What is to done to use a file containing more than one words or passages?